# How to convert mime text to utf-8 in flex

Tags: apache-flex, mime

Hi I'm wondering how I can convert some mime text like =?ISO-8859-1?Q? into utf-8 so it's readable for the users.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from **file properties** (Rt Clikc File in Eclipse) in **resource**

[image]

hopes that helps

Comment: I'm getting my data from a remote service and not a file, so I don't think I can use that.

Comment: means when you call method from main method not from Flex

Comment: @Imran yes it prints correctly I've put my data in a datagrid I have a lot of mime types in one column wich makes it unreadable.

Comment: it's an email from personal text. So I need to convert it in my itemrenderer in datagrid but I hava no clue how

Comment: what do you mean with prints correctly, I get the data that I needed but that data is in mime type. So it's incorrect for my application it needs to convert somehow in flex. I can't change the mimetype in my php

Comment: nevermind, I parsed my results in php where I could use the imap_mime_header_decode to decode the each field. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I mean that, if all character print on console in readable form as you wants in Flex, i dont know much about PHP, how you are passing data to FLEX?

Answer (score 0):

- Get your text into ByteArray
- Use [readMultiByte()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readMultiByte%28%29) and specify encoding you need (they used iso-8859-1 right in the example, he-he.)